# Foundation custom select not working inside button bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to use Zurb Foundation 4 in my website. I am using the "custom forms" feature of foundation which applies special styling to form elements as described in this link.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html

The trouble I am having is that the HTML select elements don't work when embedded inside a button bar. For example, the following code works

```
<form class="custom">
        <select>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
 </form>
```

But the same code embedded inside a button group does not work

```
<div class="button-bar">
<ul class="button-group">
            <li>
                <form class="custom">
                    <select>
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have created a JSfiddle which demonstrates the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/5JbZB/4/

Any ideas on what could be causing this? My initial thought was that the dropdown of the select is being hidden by some outer CSS class overriding the depth but I have had no luck identifying the offending element.

Comment: question is incomplete. include the css you are using. the problem is in css

Comment: The question is complete. The CSS is loaded as a external resource in the fiddle link. I do not have any CSS outside of what is provided by the standard foundation framework download. Please learn to use a fiddle before downvoting the question

Comment: I think the issue might be Google Chrome. According to the console, it is refusing to execute Foundation scripts from Github because its "MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." The fiddle works fine on my Firefox.

Comment: @stellarchariot - I have updated the fiddle with scripts from a CDN instead of Github. It should work on all browsers now. Thanks for alerting me to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe I missed this, but here is a much better solution.

```
.button-group .custom.dropdown{
  overflow:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JbZB/7/

Comment: If this ends up being selected I think I might adjust it a bit and try to push it to the Foundation framework.

Comment: Very nice! Now the select works perfectly. The only remaining problem is that your javascript code causes the content below the button bar to shift down when the select is opened. Here is fiddle demonstrating the issue http://jsfiddle.net/5JbZB/6/. I think some CSS combined with your javascript should do the trick! Thanks

Comment: My fat fingers seem to have awarded the bounty to the wrong answer. I will try to contact support and have the bounty awarded to this answer. Please bear with me!

Comment: Try that one, I edited it after I found something I missed, sorry for leading you down the wrong direction. If it works can you give it an upvote :)

Comment: Gosh! I could have sworn that I tried the overflow but must have done it on a different element. This works great! Thanks

Comment: If you want to award the bounty I think you have to unselect me as the answer and re-select the answer.

Comment: Did you have any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Include this css in CSS box.this should do the work.**

```
/* We use these to controls height and width styles. */
$f-dropdown-max-width: 200px;
$f-dropdown-height: auto;
$f-dropdown-max-height: none;
$f-dropdown-margin-top: 2px;

/* We use this to control the background color */
$f-dropdown-bg: #fff;

/* We use this to set the border styles for dropdowns. */
$f-dropdown-border-style: solid;
$f-dropdown-border-width: 1px;
$f-dropdown-border-color: darken(#fff, 20%);

/* We use these to style the triangle pip. */
$f-dropdown-triangle-size: 6px;
$f-dropdown-triangle-color: #fff;
$f-dropdown-triangle-side-offset: 10px;

/* We use these to control styles for the list elements. */
$f-dropdown-list-style: none;
$f-dropdown-font-color: #555;
$f-dropdown-font-size: emCalc(14px);
$f-dropdown-list-padding: emCalc(5px) emCalc(10px);
$f-dropdown-line-height: emCalc(18px);
$f-dropdown-list-hover-bg: #eeeeee;
$dropdown-mobile-default-float: 0;

/* We use this to control the styles for when the dropdown has custom content. */
$f-dropdown-content-padding: emCalc(20px);
```

> **but do have in mind that your classname name should equate with the css tags. So first you will have to equate them**

And check this link if you are interested in making it through JavaScript [click here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

Comment: I have already added the required CSS and Javascript files in the fiddle. Click on the "External Resources" tab on the left side in jsfiddle to see the loaded files. Without those files, the first example would not work!

Answer (score 0):

Simply try like this (http://jsfiddle.net/5JbZB/1/):

```
<div class="row">
    Button bar with Zurb Foundation's custom select
    <div class="button-bar">
        <form class="custom">
            <select>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <ul class="button-group">
            <li><a href="#">button</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for the drop down but I need my select to be inside a "button-group" because it is going to be grouped with a few more elements

Answer (score 0):

**Probably you should see these two links::**

> [**Drop-down list inside add button or panel**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23925/drop-down-list-inside-add-button-or-panel)

---

> Through [**JavaScript**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

---

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is the button group UL and LI are smaller than you are expecting them to be.  The custom form select element has a 100% width, however since the UL and the LI for the button-bar are much smaller than 100% width, 50px if I remember right, then your select will only be that wide.

If you add the css below you should be good to go.  If you are planning on using button groups other places you can add another class to do the same thing.

```
.button-group {
    width:100%;
}
.button-group li {
    width:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle Link for Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/5JbZB/3/)

[Image](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/8370/a4w5.jpg)

Comment: Tried your example but it did not work for me. Which browser did you use? I tried it in IE9, Chrome 27 and Safari 6

Comment: Can you check the image i just added to the answer to see if that is what you are expecting to see and if that is what you see in the fiddler?

Comment: -Thanks for clarifying! I updated my fiddle today because the original fiddle used external resources from github which is a bad idea. Your image shows that that you were using the old fiddle without any styles or javascript working. My apologies for the confusion. Could you try my fiddle link again?

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddler, I will update my answer soon as I have it.  I found out why the dropdown is not displaying, just need to fix it. :)